# Calculate consecutive days in Python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a table with visiting dates with different customer IDs. The table is below. Some customers come a few days in a row, stop a few days, and then come back a few days in a row again. I want to calculate the consecutive days for each customer. In my case, each customer may have a few consecutive days. for example, customer 1 has 3 consecutive days and has another 4 consecutive days. how can I get all these consecutive-days numbers and then get the biggest one?

```
id  visit_date
1   1/2/2022
1   1/3/2022
1   1/4/2022
1   1/7/2022
1   1/8/2022
1   1/9/2022
1   1/10/2022
2   1/1/2022
2   1/2/2022
2   1/4/2022
2   1/6/2022
2   1/7/2022
2   1/8/2022
2   1/9/2022
2   1/10/2022
3   1/3/2022
3   1/4/2022
3   1/5/2022
4   1/3/2022
4   1/4/2022
4   1/8/2022
```

I tried different ways and I didn't find any solution. my expectation is:

```
id  consecutive_days
1   3
1   4
2   2
2   5
3   2
4   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in the max number, you can skip using a double `groupby` and go with a numpy aggregation function, which should be efficient on large datasets:

```
out = (pd
   .to_datetime(df['visit_date'], dayfirst=False)
   .groupby(df['id'])
   .agg(lambda g: np.diff(np.nonzero(np.r_[g.diff().ne('1d'), len(g)])[0]).max())
   #.reset_index(name='consecutive_days') # optional
)
```

Output:

```
id
1    4
2    5
3    3
4    2
Name: visit_date, dtype: int64
```

Output as frame:

```
   id  consecutive_days
0   1                 4
1   2                 5
2   3                 3
3   4                 2
```

Intermediate before aggregation:

```
id
1       [3, 4]
2    [2, 1, 5]
3          [3]
4       [2, 1]
Name: visit_date, dtype: object
```

Finally, if you want to exclude `1`, you can do it **after** aggregation (`out[out>1]` if a Series,  `out.query('consecutive_days>1')` if DataFrame)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dates are in ascending order inside each customer-id, you could do find the difference between rows and then sum the rows that are equal to 1 for each group.

```py
consecutive_days_per_id = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda group: (pd.to_datetime(group['date']).dt.day.diff() == 1).sum())
```

Note: if your column is already of type datetime, you can ignore the "pd.to_datetime()" part.

Comment: this one is not working. it adds all the consecutive days together and doesn't separate the different consecutive days.

Answer (score 0):

```
(df.assign(c = pd.to_datetime(df['visit_date']).diff().ne('1 day').cumsum())
   .groupby(['id', 'c'], as_index = False)
   .count().loc[lambda x: x.visit_date>1]
   .drop(columns = 'c')
   .rename(columns = {'visit_date':'consecutive_days'}))

   id  consecutive_days
0   1                 3
1   1                 4
2   2                 2
4   2                 5
5   3                 3
6   4                 2
```

Comment: what's ne(days)? I never used this before. Could you explain? Thanks.

Comment: @jingchunliu sorry bout that. it was supposed to be `'1day'`

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
grp = (pd.to_datetime(df['visit_date'])
         .groupby(df['id']).diff().ne('1day')
         .groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
)


out = (df.groupby(['id', grp]).size()[lambda x: x > 1]
       .droplevel(1).reset_index(name='consecutive_days')
)
```

out:

```
    id  consecutive_days
0   1   3
1   1   4
2   2   2
3   2   5
4   3   3
5   4   2
```

---

get biggest one

```
result = out.groupby('id').max()
```

result:

```
    consecutive_days
id  
1   4
2   5
3   3
4   2
```